# Ajax Query Isn't Going Through to PHP Script

Tags: php

I am trying to run a simple scenario in which: a form is submitted -> jquery ajax request for JSON data -> PHP script reads from the database and encodes to JSON -> data is shown on my page.

the fields on the MySQL are: `Name` and `Password`

step 1 - my form - **Search.php**

```
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Query.js"></script>

    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" id="formoid" action="">
       <input type="text" name="enterpass" placeholder="Enter Password">
       <input type="submit" name="subbpass">
    </form>

    <input type="text" id="showname"><br/>
    <input type="text" id="showpassword">
```

step 2 - my jquery file- **Query.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formoid").submit(function(){
    alert("form submitted")  // this alert goes through
    var passid = $("#enterpass").val();
       $.ajax({
          url: "ModelQuery.php",
          method: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          data: {args: passid},
          success: function(data)
           {

           console.log('ajax successfully sent'); // this alert isn't working

           $("#showname").text(data.Name); // data isn't showing here
           $("#showpassword").text(data.Password);
            console.log(data); // or here ...


          }
       });

    });

});
```

and lastly, my php -- ModelQuery.php -- **I omitted some code lines but that script is the normal script for reading from the database and has worked for me in the past.**

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['args'])) {


        $arg = $_POST['args']
        $CON = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','testdb');
        // ....
        $QUERY = "SELECT * FROM testtable where Password = '$arg'";

       // ...
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($RESULT))
        {



            $jsonresults["Name"] = $row['Name'];
            $jsonresults["Password"] = $row['Password'];

        }
         echo json_encode($jsonresults);

 }
```

the alert in the Jquery script right after the form is submitted does go through, but the ajax itself doesn't show anything, neither on the console nor on my two textboxs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: the form is submitted using the traditional `submit` button and the jQuery code above seems ( don't use jQuery ) to be processing the submit event which, at that stage, is in the process of submitting the form to the same page.  You might want to call `event.preventDefault()` or change the `submit` to `button`

Comment: Sidenote: Please ensure you use superglobals with caution. Your db is currently vulnerable, that would be easy to query pretty much anything from your db. Including DELETE.
See this question for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Interesting @charj. Thanks for the comment, ill look deeper into this.

Comment: Prepared statements are a nice way to get around this problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, which consisted of 3 different problems:
1) my input textbox `<input type="text" name="enterpass" placeholder="Enter Password">` didn't have id attribute, only name
2) as @RamRaider suggested, I changed it to button and gave it id as well.

3) one of the lines in the php didn't have `;` at its end..

Thanks you!